# How to check if it's Saturday/Sunday?

Tags: java, calendar

What this code does is print the dates of the current week from Monday to Friday. It works fine, but I want to ask something else: If today is Saturday or Sunday I want it to show the next week. How do I do that?

Here's my working code so far (thanks to StackOverflow!!):

```
// Get calendar set to current date and time
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

// Set the calendar to monday of the current week
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);

// Print dates of the current week starting on Monday to Friday
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd/MM/yyyy");
for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
    System.out.println(df.format(c.getTime()));
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}
```

Thanks a lot! I really appreciate it as I've been searching for the solution for hours...

Answer (score 29):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    // Set the calendar to monday of the current week
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);

    // Print dates of the current week starting on Monday to Friday
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd/MM/yyyy");
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(df.format(c.getTime()));
        int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        if (dayOfWeek == Calendar.FRIDAY) { // If it's Friday so skip to Monday
            c.add(Calendar.DATE, 3);
        } else if (dayOfWeek == Calendar.SATURDAY) { // If it's Saturday skip to Monday
            c.add(Calendar.DATE, 2);
        } else {
            c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }

        // As Cute as a ZuZu pet.
        //c.add(Calendar.DATE, dayOfWeek > Calendar.THURSDAY ? (9 - dayOfWeek) : 1);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Mon 03/01/2011
Tue 04/01/2011
Wed 05/01/2011
Thu 06/01/2011
Fri 07/01/2011
Mon 10/01/2011
Tue 11/01/2011
Wed 12/01/2011
Thu 13/01/2011
Fri 14/01/2011
Mon 17/01/2011
```

If you want to be cute you can replace the if/then/else with

```
c.add(Calendar.DATE, dayOfWeek > 5 ? (9 - dayOfWeek) : 1);
```

but I really wanted something easily understood and readable.

Comment: thanks for the reply! If I run it it says that the day of the week is 2 (it's sunday here). So I've put it in that for and Monday start with 3.... is that correct ?

Comment: Maybe use 'dayOfWeek == Calendar.FRIDAY' in preference to 'dayOfWeek == 6', etc.?

Comment: Sorry for another reply but I gotta say that you absolutely rock... This has been annoying me no end since I'm a beginner at Java at college! Have an awesome year!

Comment: @Martin you are correct, he shouldn't be using Calendar.FRIDAY instead. Thats what I get for writing fast code. I appreciate it. +1 for you.

Answer (score 26):

## tl;dr

Core code concept:

```
EnumSet.of( DayOfWeek.SATURDAY , DayOfWeek.SUNDAY )           // Instantiate a n implementation of `Set` highly optimized in both memory usage and execution speed for collecting enum objects. 
       .contains(                                             // Ask if our target `DayOfWeek` enum object is in our `Set`. 
            LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )  // Determine today’s date as seen by the people of a particular region (time zone).
                     .getDayOfWeek()                          // Determine the `DayOfWeek` enum constant representing the day-of-week of this date.
        )
```

## java.time

The modern way is with the java.time classes.

The `DayOfWeek` enum provides seven objects, for Monday-Sunday.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
DayOfWeek dow = today.getDayOfWeek();
```

Define the weekend as a set of `DayOfWeek` objects. Note that `EnumSet` is an especially fast and low-memory implementation of `Set` designed to hold `Enum` objects such as `DayOfWeek`.

```
Set<DayOfWeek> weekend = EnumSet.of( DayOfWeek.SATURDAY , DayOfWeek.SUNDAY );
```

Now we can test if today is a weekday or a weekend.

```
Boolean todayIsWeekend = weekend.contains( dow );
```

The Question said we want to jump to the start of next week if this is a weekend. To do that, use a `TemporalAdjuster` which provides for classes that can manipulate date-time objects. In java.time we have [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). This means we produce new instances based on the values within an existing object rather than alter ("mutate") the original. The [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) class (note the plural 's') provides several handy implementations of `TemporalAdjuster` including `next( DayOfWeek )`.

```
DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.MONDAY ;
LocalDate startOfWeek = null ;
if( todayIsWeekend ) {
    startOfWeek = today.with( TemporalAdjusters.next( firstDayOfWeek ) );
} else {
    startOfWeek = today.with( TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame( firstDayOfWeek ) );
}
```

We soft-code the length of the week in case our definition of weekend ever changes.

```
LocalDate ld = startOfWeek ;
int countDaysToPrint = ( DayOfWeek.values().length - weekend.size() );
for( int i = 1 ; i <= countDaysToPrint ; i++ ) {
    System.out.println( ld );
    // Set up the next loop.
    ld = ld.plusDays( 1 );
}
```

See [live code in IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/FAgVfi).

[image]

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts ***ThreeTen-Backport*** (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here is short answer using Java 8, all you need to do is to convert your Calendar instance to LocalDateTime and leverage DayOfWeek enum to check if it's Saturday or Sunday, here you go...

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd/MM/yyyy");
        for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {

           //following line does all magic for you
            if(LocalDateTime.ofInstant(c.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault()).getDayOfWeek()!=DayOfWeek.SATURDAY && LocalDateTime.ofInstant(c.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault()).getDayOfWeek()!=DayOfWeek.SUNDAY)

            System.out.println(df.format(c.getTime()));
            c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }
```