# Java check if date is next sunday

Tags: java, date

I get a date and want to check if it is the next sunday.I found alot of code with Calendar etc, but I can't find the right code. And I don't really understand how I can know if it is the next sunday from a date.

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 3):

Break the problem down:

1. Get today's date: `new Date();`
2. Get the day of the week for today's date.
3. Advance forward to Sunday
4. Get that date

Comment: "Advance forward to Sunday" is non-trivial though

Comment: Really?  A loop wouldn't do it?  Loop over seven days and break out when you hit Sunday.  Seems trivial to me.

Answer (score 3):

First of, I recommend [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) as a much better Date/Time API than `Calendar`.

As for your processing it breaks down into easy steps:

1. Construct `DateTime` objects for the two dates
2. Check that the target date is a Sunday
3. Check that the difference between them is between 0 and 7 days

Answer (score 0):

If you look for nice Date management, check this out [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637238/how-to-check-if-its-saturday-sunday) might be helpful to you , you can chek by dayOfWeek == Calendar.SUNDAY after adding one day

Answer (score 0):

With [Lamma Date](http://lamma.io) it's very easy to first obtain next Sunday, then we can use `equals` check if the date is next Sunday.

```
    Date today = new Date(2014, 7, 1);  // assume today is 2014-07-01
    Date nextSunday = today.next(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY);     // 2014-07-06
```

Comment: Make sure you've read the guidelines about self-promotion: http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior

Comment: Thanks for reminding me this. IMO this one is a relevant answer which: 1) indeed solved the problem. 2) provide more code examples. Will take a look at how http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/community-promotion-ads/ works, thanks!